# How to get unknown request parameter in @RequestParam SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, datatables

I am trying to implement datatable editor with spring boot ,but the client to server data varies for create ,update and delete even not constant for create as well and depends on fields
I have implemented this till now

```
@RequestMapping(value="/datatabledata" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
            @ResponseBody
            public String datatabledata(HttpServletRequest request)
            {
                Enumeration<String> params = request.getParameterNames(); 
                while(params.hasMoreElements()){
                 String paramName = params.nextElement();
                 System.out.println("Parameter Name - "+paramName+", Value - "+request.getParameter(paramName));
                }
                //System.out.println(data);
                //System.out.println(request.);
                //Map<String,String>ak=new HashMap<>();
                //ak.put("data", "hello ");
                return "done";
            }
```

Above code prints following output on console for create

```
Parameter Name - action, Value - create
Parameter Name - data[0][username], Value - dddddd
Parameter Name - data[0][date], Value - 2018-11-28
Parameter Name - data[0][balance], Value - dddddddddd
```

and this for edit

```
Parameter Name - action, Value - edit
Parameter Name - data[5bfab595507af613f409c0c4][username], Value - four
Parameter Name - data[5bfab595507af613f409c0c4][date], Value - 2018-11-25
Parameter Name - data[5bfab595507af613f409c0c4][balance], Value - 9000.0
```

The only constant parameter here is action and so I can use

```
@RequestParam("action")
```

but how to get rest data ?? something like `@RequestParam() String data`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DTO class which can be mapped from the request and can be used further.

```
        @RequestMapping(value="/datatabledata" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
        @ResponseBody
        public String datatabledata(HttpServletRequest request)
        {
            UserDTO object = new ObjectMapper().setDateFormat(simpleDateFormat).readValue(request.getReader(), UserDTO.class);
            performYourOperation(object);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see we should utilize REST in more richer way here.

So create three different controller method handlling create, update and delete and maps them to difference HTTP methods like below :

```
//For Create. Take the parameter as (@RequestBody List<User>)
@RequestMapping(value="/datatabledata" , method=RequestMethod.POST) 
//For Update/Edit, Take the parameter as (@RequestBody List<User>)
@RequestMapping(value="/datatabledata" , method=RequestMethod.PUT)
//For Delete, Just take either list of ids or id to be delete. Nothiing else required 
@RequestMapping(value="/datatabledata" , method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
```

Now you don't need `action` as parameter. Client just need to specify the correct http method.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@RequestParam Map<String,String> allRequestParams` in  your endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/datatabledata" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String datatabledata(@RequestParam Map<String,String> allRequestParams) {
   / ... rest of your code
}
```